# I am using unofficial package of stockx api in javascript but i am getting the following error while using login api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

> ```
> (node:1436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Status code error 403 - Response:
> ```
>
> {"appId":"PX16uD0kOF","jsClientSrc":"/16uD0kOF/init.js","firstPartyEnabled":true,"vid":"","uuid":"645cdd54-857b-11ec-9f49-4c4d7149756f","hostUrl":"/16uD0kOF/xhr","blockScript":"/16uD0kOF/captcha/captcha.js?a=c&u=645cdd54-857b-11ec-9f49-4c4d7149756f&v=&m=0"}
> at Object.module.exports [as submitCredentials] (C:\xampp\htdocs\stockx\node_modules\stockx-api\src\api\login\submitcredentials.js:41:43)

```
const StockXAPI = require('stockx-api');
const stockX = new StockXAPI();

console.log('Logging in...');

stockX.login({
    user: 'accountemailhere', 
    password: 'accountpassword'
})
.then(() => console.log('Logged in successfully!'));
```

> Api link:https://github.com/matthew1232/stockx-api

Comment: An HTTP 403 error is a Forbidden error, often returned when invalid credentials are supplied.

Comment: well i have cross checked my credentials

Comment: Have you tried looking at the issues on the Github page?: https://github.com/matthew1232/stockx-api/issues/32

Comment: yes there were no answers there

Comment: The answer is there, it is at the Stock X end which has broken the unofficial API. There is nothing that can be done

Answer (score 1):

this is the cloudflare waf that is blocking your requests because they are suspect and made by a bot.
You can't fix that since this is the only stockx api available.